# Rails - How to populate form fields with default value from DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have some form fields for email, name, phone, ID etc, that I want to populate when a form loads with current_user.email etc. The values for the form fields are stored in a db field called default_value. The following works, but it puts the literal string current_user.email in the form field. How do I get it to actually output the email and other values so it looks like myname@stack.com?

```
<%= form.text_field field.name, required: field.required, value: field.default_value, class: "form_control" %>
```

Comment: Are all values stored into 1 db field? Sounds a bit crazy to be honest. Maybe you can add your `schema.rb` and the matching controller file + complete view file to give it more context.

Comment: Think of this like a form builder. Certain records depending on their type need different form fields for the user to fill out. So I am storing the field type and any other options in the DB for the classification_fields model. Just wondering how to make it display the correct value. If I hard code current_user.email in the field it works and displays the email address. If I pull the value current_user.email from the DB it does not work. It displays current_user.email.

Comment: Ahh now i understand. So the current_user.email is stored as a string in your DB and you want to 'convert' it to code. You can use `eval` for that: `value: eval(field.default_value)`